# Office Setup Configuration

Tags: vb6, ms-office

i need help to fix my visual basic 6.0. When vb6 start ups, It shows some Microsoft Offices Setup configuration that shows at everytime. If i cancel, I can continue the VB6, But some of component always shows this installation setup again. When I restart the VB Program, The setup configuration also shows everytime...

Any ideas to fix this? This really eat more times.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vb6 apps have this quirk when some msi installer got its registry settings hosed. Have you run a regcleaner recently? Anyway the solution is usually to insert any CD that may be asked for (MS apps such as Office) and let it do its thing once then it usually never reoccurs. You may even have to to a repair install of the Office app concerned.